# Metodos de otras clases python

Tags: python, api, poo, python-2.7, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy tratando de implementar interfaces graficas con POO. Quería separar las clases en distintos archivos. Entonces tengo en un archivo el frame de un menú con botones y quiero que el botón salir cierre la aplicación. El error que me sale es el siguiente: "name 'Ventana' is not defined".
La idea general es tener todo separado en para poder reutilizar en otros proyectos. Paso el codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from turtle import *
    import Start as sm
    from Ventana import *
    import Palabras as p

    class Menu(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, unaVentana:Ventana = None): 
          super().__init__(unaVentana)
          self.laVentana = unaVentana
          self.config(bg="black")
          self.pack(expand=True, fill="both", ipadx=10, ipady=10)
          self.boxTitulo = self.contenedorTitulo()
          self.boxMenu = ContenedorBotones(self)
      def contenedorTitulo(self):
          boxTitulo = tk.Canvas(self, background="black",highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
          self.archivo_titulo = tk.PhotoImage(file="imagenes/nuevo_titulo.png")
          boxTitulo.create_image(5,0, image=self.archivo_titulo, anchor="nw")
          boxTitulo.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.17, relwidth=0.70, relheight=0.50)
    
          return boxTitulo
 
    class ContenedorBotones:
       def __init__(self, framePrincipal:Menu = None):
         self.frameMenu = framePrincipal
         self.contenedor= tk.Frame(self.frameMenu)
         self.contenedor.config(background="red")    
         self.contenedor.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.70, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.25)
         self.cargarBotones()
        
    
      def cargarBotones(self):
         self.jugar = Boton(self.contenedor, "JUGAR", 1)
         self.palabras = Boton(self.contenedor, "PALABRAS", 2)
         self.configuracion = Boton(self.contenedor, "CONFIG", 3)
         self.salir = Boton(self.contenedor, "SALIR", 4)
         self.salir.boton["command"] = self.frameMenu.laVentana.cerrarAplicacion()**
```

#########################################
EN OTRO ARCHIVO TENGO:
#########################################

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import Menu as mn
    class Ventana:
       def __init__(self, nombre, ancho, alto):
          self.ventanaPrincipal = tk.Tk()
          self.configurarTamanio(ancho, alto)
          self.configurarNombre(nombre)
          self.correrAplicacion()
          self.ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
    
       def configurarTamanio(self, ancho, alto):
          ancho_pantalla = self.ventanaPrincipal.winfo_screenwidth() 
          alto_pantalla = self.ventanaPrincipal.winfo_screenheight() 
          posicion_x = int((ancho_pantalla/2) - (ancho/2)) 
          posicion_y = int((alto_pantalla/2) - (alto/2))
          tamanioPosicion = str(ancho) + "x" + str(alto) + "+" + str(posicion_x) + "+" + 
          str(posicion_y)
          self.ventanaPrincipal.geometry(tamanioPosicion)
          self.ventanaPrincipal.resizable(0,0) 
    
       def configurarNombre(self, nombre):
          self.ventanaPrincipal.title(nombre)
       def correrAplicacion(self):
          self.menuPrincipal = mn.Menu(ventana = self.ventanaPrincipal)

       def cerrarAplicacion(self):
          self.ventanaPrincipal.destroy**
```

Comment: ¿En que línea sale el error? Danos el contenido de la línea misma.

Comment: File "d:\python SISTEMA VENTAS\Menu.py", line 16, in Menu
    def __init__(self, unaVentana:Ventana = None): 
NameError: name 'Ventana' is not defined

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error. Todo parece en orden.

Comment: no se como resolverlo. def __init__(self, unaVentana:Ventana = None), en esta linea me salta. Si le saco ":Ventana" no puedo acceder a las funciones del objeto. y lo que quiero hacer ahora es poder cerrar la aplicacion

Comment: En realidad Python es *typeless*; no tiene tipos. Las anotaciones son irrelevantes para la ejecución. Le puedes pasar cualquier cosa en tanto implemente los métodos que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias. lo soluciones poniendo todas las clases en un solo modulo